# Turning url from SQL into clickable link

Tags: php, sql, hyperlink, clickable

I'm trying to make it so any text url inserted into the 'tag' column of my sql database will be turned into a clickable link within the php table. Right now, I'm having to manually put the link html in the database, which I don't want to do.

This is the code I've got:

```
<?php 
  mysql_connect(localhost, user, pw) or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db(database) or die(mysql_error());
?>

<table id=table class=display>
<thead><tr><th>Owner</th><th>Soquili's Name</th><th>Sex</th><th>Generation</th><th>Parents</th><th>Kind</th><th>Theme</th><th>Colorist</th><th>Tag</th><th>Alt 1</th><th>Alt 2</th><th>Alt 3</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<?php

  // Result Limit
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM soquili limit 25";
  $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());


  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  //Reference


  $name     = $row['owner'];
  $soq    = $row['soq'];
  $sex    = $row['sex'];
  $gen     = $row['gen'];
  $parents = $row['parents'];
  $kind    = $row['kind'];
  $theme    = $row['theme'];
  $colorist    = $row['colorist'];
  $tag    = $row['tag'];
  $alt1    = $row['alt1'];
  $alt2    = $row['alt2'];
  $alt3    = $row['alt3'];

// looped row
echo 
"<tr><td>".$name."</td>
<td>".$soq."</td><td>".$sex."</td>
<td>".$gen."</td>
<td>".$parents."</td>
<td>".$kind."</td>
<td>".$theme."</td>
<td>".$colorist."</td> 
<td><a href=\".$tag.\">Tag</a></td>
<td>".$alt1."</td> 
<td>".$alt2."</td>
<td>".$alt3."</td> 
</tr>";

}
?>
</tbody></table>
```

I can't see why it's not working.

This is my website:
http://rpwith.us/Test2/

And I have a test entry (search for Weeese) with a text URL that simply won't turn clickable. Any suggestions?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You know...if you use double quotes to encapsulate the echo-ed bit, you do not need to concatenate the variables. ie: you can write it like this: echo "Hello, nice to meet you $name";

Comment: The code above does not match the output on your site.

Comment: I'm not sure how it doesn't match the output? My apologies, this is my first time using PHP.

Comment: Not need to concatenate with `echo`. You can use comma's (,) to separate instead of (.) and with double quotes there isn't even any need for those either as @Dacto said.

Comment: When I attempt to do double quotes I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes on the line with the `a` tag are wrong.

Correct:

```
<td><a href=\"".$tag."\">Tag</a></td>
```

Explanation:

The `\"` serves to insert a literal quote, but you want to have another quote to end the string literal, so that the `. $tag .` is parsed as PHP code.

The way you did it, the ". $tag ." part is part of the string literal; however, as you're using double quotes, the `$tag` is replaced automatically by PHP, **but the dots remain**. Result: You have pair of extra dots in your output.

Comment: Thank you, and that explanation helped a lot! I've edited it to the above code but I am still seeing a text link for some reason.